# Asymptotic complexity of $f(n) = f(\sqrt{n}) + n$

Tags: complex-analysis, algorithms

In this attached [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqa8d.png), it is asked to find to time complexity of f(n). We can simplify this equation to $f(n) = f(\sqrt{n}) + n$ which can be further modified as $s(m) = s(m/2) + 2^m$ by taking $ n = 2^m $ and $s(m) = f(2^m)$. How can I find the complexity of $f(n)$ from here?

Comment: A function has no *time complexity*.

Comment: As Yves noted, you  are probably asking for the asymptotic complexity of $f(n)$. From $s(m) = s(m/2) + 2^m$ you can use the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) and find your answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that point. @YvesDaoust

Comment: Here, $f(n) = 2^n$. I think master theorem stands for $f(n) = O(n^k log{^p}n)$ for some $k, p$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is a version of the master theorem with the regularity condition for $f(n)=\Omega(n^c)$. It's on wiki. Otherwise you can just expand $f(n)$ -- how many terms are there ?

Comment: I think there is $log m$ number of terms if we expand s(m) in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By repeated application of the recurrence on powers $n=2^{2^m}$,
$$n+n^{1/2}+n^{1/4}+\cdots4+f(2)\sim n$$ because there are $\log_2(\log_2(n))$ terms and $\sqrt n\log_2(\log_2(n))=o(n)$.

Hence

$$f(n)=\Theta(n).$$